# How can I set the path environnment variable in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, path, ilmerge

I'm using ILMerge in my post build step.
For interoperability reason I would like use ILMerge relative path.
How can I set the *path* environment variable accessible from my post build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ILMerge install path isn't relative to anything.  If you want to add it to the PATH environment variable then write this in your postbuild event:

```
set path = %path%;$(programfiles)\microsoft\ilmerge
```

Comment: This would be the trick to my current project. Isn't there a way to set the path one time for all my project?

Comment: Change your system environment.  Control Panel + System + Advanced.  Not recommended if you like your project to build on other machines without hassle.

Comment: I accept your post but I don't agree with you: The build environment is a per-machine configuration. If I want to build my app on another machine I should install ILMerge then add it to the path. Your first proposition leads to add ILMerge path to all your current projects.

Comment: No need to agree.  I just hand out the bullets, you have to pull the trigger yourself.